# Show current position annotation by default

Tags: ios, annotations, mapkit, default, show

I have an current location annotation (blue dot) showing in mapkit. Annotation shows after taping the blue dot,
how can I have the annotation showing by default?, when I start the view? whit out tapping the pin.

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
    for(MKAnnotationView *annotationView in views) {
        if(annotationView.annotation == mv.userLocation) {

            self.mapView.userLocation.title= @"Current";
            self.mapView.userLocation.subtitle= @"Location";

            MKCoordinateRegion region;
            MKCoordinateSpan span;

            span.latitudeDelta=0.002;
            span.longitudeDelta=0.002; 

            CLLocationCoordinate2D location=mv.userLocation.coordinate;

            region.span=span;
            region.center=location;

            [mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
            [mv regionThatFits:region];

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: does your code work? There's something missing, such as mapView addAnnotation to call it… Oh, right didn't realize showUserLocation indeed worked with addAnnotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, selectAnnotation should work, wouldn't it? Just performSelector after a small time.

.... same code as before but insert this:

```
            id annotation = annotationView.annotation;
            [self performSelector:@selector(selectUserLocation:) withObject:annotation afterDelay:0.1f];
        }
    }
}

- (void)selectUserLocation:(id)annotation{
    [self.mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
}
```