# Android : How to show user current location using default map (v2)?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-api-2

Hi all i am working on google map v2. I need to show the blue icon (indicates user current location). Like locationoverlay change option in v1(http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=148) is there any option to show the user current location by default with v2?

Thanks all

Comment: Google it, before SO.

Comment: Please vote to close your question.

Comment: Like how we show in ios i need to show in android. I could'nt get the right code .(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555583/show-current-position-annotation-by-default). Can you give me the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question. Before asking this question i wasted most of my time to get it.

```
GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

The simple solutions to show current location on google map api v2.

Comment: Whats wrong with just typing `Current location mapview android` on google and getting your answers dude ?